# Is there a meaning of in names of AWS instance type prefixes? or it just random?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

You will find these prefixes in [aws documentation](http://ref:%20https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-types.html) over various instances types:
'a', 'm', 't', 'r', 'c', 'u', 'x', 'd', 'i', 'f', 'g'.

I can **only** assume

```
  C stands for Compute
  R stands for RAM 
  G stands for GPU or Graphics
  I stands for I/O 
  M stands for medium??
```

I wonder if other prefixes have some kind of meaning too.

Comment: [zethw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1463767) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66859813) saying "I have never been able to find a definitive list of what the prefixes mean but here is a pretty good summary comparison chart. [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-types.html#instance-type-summary-table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-types.html#instance-type-summary-table)"

Comment: This is now [fully documented here](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is what I gathered a bit back from ACloudGuru cert training, these may change or remove in the future as AWS changes them.  Probably a few more that I'm missing.

```
D for density
R for RAM
M for main choice for general purpose apps
C for compute
G for Graphics
I for IOPs
F for FPGA
T for cheap general purpose (think t2 micro)
P for graphic (think pics)
X for extreme memory
H for High disk throughput
A for arm base processor instance
```

Comment: Woow. Nice. I always struggled with X, but now I think I can remember it. I also think if it has `a` in the name its for AMD, and if it has `n` its for enhanced networking.

Comment: Still can't understand why T stands for cheap general purpose :)

Comment: BTW, what is the difference between P and G, I and H?

Comment: @EugeneMaysyuk T stands for Threshold and describes [Burstable instances](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/#Burstable_Performance_Instances) that accumulate credits when CPU is below the Threshold and use those credits when it's bursting. Good for infrequent workloads with lots of idle time in between.